# Unexpected behaviour of Antlr4 lexer after invoking 'more' command

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have 'more' command in one of rules in my lexer grammar. As a result a single character token matches multiple character text, which must not happen or i am missing something. Here is the grammar:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;
    StartQuote
        : '"'
        -> pushMode(BeforeTextMode)
        ;
mode BeforeTextMode;
    SwitchToTextMode
        : .
        -> more, mode(TextMode)
        ;
mode TextMode;
    Text
        : ~'"'+
        ;
    EndQuote
        : '"'
        -> popMode
        ;
```

Here is the test program:

```cs
class Program
{
    static string InputText1 = "\"x\"";
    static string InputText2 = "\"xy\"";

    static string[] TokenTypeNames = new string[] { "StartQuote", "Text", "EndQuote" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string TokenSequence1 = GetTokenSequence(InputText1);
        string TokenSequence2 = GetTokenSequence(InputText2);

        Console.WriteLine(TokenSequence1);
        Console.WriteLine(TokenSequence2);
    }

    static string GetTokenSequence(string InputText)
    {
        var Lexer = new MyLexer(new AntlrInputStream(InputText));
        string TokenSequence = "";
        for (var Token = Lexer.NextToken(); Token.Type != -1; Token = Lexer.NextToken())
            TokenSequence += TokenTypeNames[Token.Type - 1] + "(" + Token.Text + ")" + " ";
        return TokenSequence;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
StartQuote(") EndQuote(x")
StartQuote(") Text(xy) EndQuote(")
```

As you can see from the program's output the single character EndQuote matches multiple character text. This only happens when the input text contains a single character between quotes.

Can you please take a look and check if i am missing anything here and if this is indeed a bug in Antlr4.

Comment: I reverted changes made by Mephy (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3614521/mephy) because as one of reviewers said "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `more` command causes the matched content to be added to the content of the next token actually produced.  For the input `"x"`, the dot matches, and consumes, the `x` from the input; there is no additional input for the `Text` rule to validly match, so no `Text` token.

The first token following the dot match is then the closing quote token, thus ending up with the content `x"`.

BTW, this behavior allows successive rule matches subject to the `more` command to accumulate content into the eventual token produced.

Comment: Apparently you are right, thank you for your clarification.